# DateTime.Ticks Argument Out of Range

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am working in MVC which have one create method to create some activity. We have one field which is activity date and it is long data type.

I need to pass user selected date as long.

**Code:**

```
long selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(userSelectedDate).ToUniversalTime().Ticks
```

**Issue:**

But after i pass this to API, i got *Argument Out of Range Exception: value*.

Please help me how can i convert to long with out this issue.

Comment: Is the API you're consuming expecting a long, or simply an int?

Comment: @smoksnes API expecting long

Comment: If the format of `userSelectedDate` is "MM/DD/YYYY" then `Convert.ToDateTime(userSelectedDate)` will gives you format exception

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code into VS2013 and it ran without any error. I don't see a problem with this code at all... Would you post the call stack? Is this code running in a Razor script or in code file?

Comment: What is the value of `userSelectedDate` that causes the exception?

Comment: [The code you provided works](http://csharppad.com/gist/8b0ee3e0698f02791f03c23121db8986) as it should. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Abbondanza yes the code is working and i got long result. But when i pass the object to API i am getting error.

Comment: Then please [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How are we supposed to help you when we can't even see the exact line that's throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `userSelectedDate`? I suspect that you'll find it to be a value that cannot be converted into a date. Or it is so close to the edge of allowable values, that the `ToUniversalTime` pushes it out of bounds.

Break this line `long selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(userSelectedDate).ToUniversalTime().Ticks` into separate steps so you can examine it one by one.

```
var a = Convert.ToDateTime(userSelectedDate);
var b = a.ToUniversalTime();
var c = b.Ticks;
```

Step through with your debugger line by line until you find the problem value.

Comment: userSelectedDate is value from datetimepicker. eg: "06/08/2016" which is in the format of MM/DD/YYYY. The issue not in my code. The error message is result return from the API

Comment: @Akhil Then how do you pass this value to the API exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am using RestSharip. I am passing activity object to AddBody method .

Comment: @Akhil You mean this [`AddBody`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/e7c65df751427298cb59f5456bbf1f59967996be/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L232) method?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes. RestRequest object AddBody method